# Increased Armor and Energy Shield not working

Tags: path-of-exile

I applied this mod in my Armourer's Bench but it doesn't take any effect. I have 299ES and 921 Armor either equipped with those gloves or not, it doesn't change.

So what does this mod increase?

[image]

Comment: I believe this is a local modifier. Meaning it will only affect said item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is: **Your armor does not have any armor or energy shield to be increased.**

Enchanted mods only apply a bonus to the **item you enchanted it onto**.

There are two types of affixes: Global and weapon-specific ones.

- Weapon specific affixes only affect the weapon it is attached to.
  Examples: +X to Armor Rating (Armor), +X Fire Elemental Damage (Weapons)
- Global affixes affect everything.
  Examples: +X to health, +X mana regeneration per second, +X elemental resistance.

Note that 'X' could be a straight addition or percentage, and that some affixes only support one or the other.

---

Here's how the game works out your mods:

**Because your glove has no Energy Shield or Armor Rating...**
Armor: 0 Armor * 1.65 = 0 Armor
Energy Shield: 0 Energy Shield * 1.65 = 0 Energy Shield.

Comment: So don't you think it shouldn't allow to apply mods that are ineffective on certain items? How players are supposed to know all this? It should be in RED and say something like 'can't apply, item has no armor or energy shield'.

Comment: Don't you think it would be overpowered? If this applied to my current build... I would have twice the armor I had now.

Comment: That's not what I meant. If it applies 0 effect it should warn about that, because now that's just wasted mod.

Comment: Technically, any affix can go onto any weapon, if edited in by the devs. It's just these limits are there to make sure things are balanced. Like who wants a "+X armor during flask effect" on a boot? And that flask effects only apply if that flask is triggered.